# DataTable edit per Row through foreach statement

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable, datarow

My problem is with my inability to fill a DataTable with values of another Datatable.
Code below:

---

```
        foreach (DataRow row1 in ds.Tables["tests"].Rows)
        {
            //Use value stored in DataTable "tests" to generate
            //new DataTable called "temp" and fill it with values

            foreach (DataRow row2 in ds.Tables["temp"].Rows)
            {
                //use values in "temp"-table to fill fields in "tests"-table
       ->       if (specific condition in Datatable "tests" is met)
                {
                    example1: row1.ItemArray[10] = Convert.ToInt64(row2.ItemArray[0]);
                    example2: ds.Tables["tests"].Rows[row1.Table.Rows.IndexOf(row1)].ItemArray[10] = Convert.ToInt64(row2.ItemArray[0]);
                }
                else if (another specific condition in Datatable "tests" is met)
                {
                    //Different fields will be filled
                }
            }
        }
```

---

When attempting to debug the program, using a stop-point at the start of the if-statement everything resolves, until the program jumps into the execution block of the if-statement.

Every line in the execution block is skipped.
Here's the readout message i get (loosely translated): 
`NonUserCode "System.Data.DataSet.Tables.get" is being skipped.` 
`NonUserCode "System.Data.DataRow.ItemArray.get" is being skipped.`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your code. First you fill the 'temp' table using values of 'test' table, then you use the values in 'temp' table to change values in 'test' table. Could you be more specific on how you fill the 'temp' table and which are the conditions to fill back the test table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to work with ItemArray.

```
if (specific condition in Datatable "tests" is met)
{
      row1[10] = Convert.ToInt64(row2[0]); //try this only.
}
else if (another specific condition in Datatable "tests" is met)
{
     //Different fields will be filled
}
```

When you are accessing ItemArray it return a local array. and by assigning value to this local array, not making any change in datatable.

Comment: It's because ".ItemArray" returns copy of internal values.

Answer (score -1):

Try to review topic: [DataRow Copy](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sa/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/a8ab4d2d-ab1b-4be6-9754-e516a923c3bf)